# How come the default value of a variable stays the same in the first iteration even after using the ++ operator in a do-while PHP loop?

Tags: php, loops, do-while

Let's say I have this following code:

```
<?php           
    $i = 1;
    $user_login = "some_name";

    do {
        $user_login_tmp = $user_login . "_" . ($i++);
        echo $user_login_tmp . "\n";
    } while ($i<10);
?>
```

As seen in this [demo](http://codepad.org/C0sP0NuV)(clickable!), the first `echo` echoes `some_name_1`.
This seems kinda weird to me since there is `$i++` there.
How come that the first output isn't `..._2`? Am I missing something?

I tried looking for an answer in the PHP manual page of the do-while loop but I couldn't find my answer there...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators check out the example about post and pre decrement operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$i++` Post-increments, it means: `return $i and then increments $i by one.`

The demo's output will start with `..._2` if you change the code to `(++$i)` [(new demo)](http://codepad.org/Nl4RZa9f)

Check out the PHP.net's page about the incrementing operator:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

```
++$a    Pre-increment   Increments $a by one, then returns $a.

$a++    Post-increment  Returns $a, then increments $a by one.

--$a    Pre-decrement   Decrements $a by one, then returns $a.

$a--    Post-decrement  Returns $a, then decrements $a by one.
```

Answer (score 4):

`$i++` does post-increment, which returns the variable, then increments by one.

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

The behaviour you described can be achieved by using pre-increment: `++$i`.

Answer (score 3):

`$i++` is a *post*-increment. That means the increment takes place after the value is taken. You can use `++$i` for a *pre*-increment, where the increment takes place before the value is taken.

Generally, most programmers prefer to use a pre-increment except where a post-increment is required. They tend to be slightly cheaper because only one value is required. With a pre-increment, you have to keep the old value around while you do the increment, which makes it slightly more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

With `$i++`, the `++` happens after getting the value of `$i`. Conversely, `++$i` increments first, then "returns" the new value.

Answer (score 1):

$i++ is using the post-operator. After $i is concatenated it is then evaluated.